# Facebook comments broken at lower width

Tags: facebook-social-plugins, facebook-comments

If I impement the Facebook comments using a lower width (in this case 380px) the content is somehow broken.

Since no custom-css is possible anymore I don't know how to fix this.

Anybody?

here is a screenshot:

[image: fb-comments]

Comment: was not allowed to add a screenshot.
please check here: http://tobiasriemenschneider.com/fb-comment.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't something you can "fix" since you have no control over content of comments plugin frame.

Actually this is well known and documented behavior, according to [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/):

> **width** - the width of the plugin in pixels. Minimum recommended width: 400px.

Comment: even if I increase to 400px or 500px is showing up like on the screenshot I linked to.

Comment: Well, this looks like a combination of translation you using (wording is much longer than in english) and your name (which is long too). The best you can do is to [file a bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/create) and hope that this get some attention from officials (be sure to attach the screenshot!)